# mutt isn't sending large messages

Tags: linux, email, mutt

I'm using mutt in the following way:

```
echo <MESSAGE> | mutt -s <SUBJECT> -- <TO-ADDR>
```

This usually works when I try small message (messages with ~10 lines in the body). But when trying very large message (a message with ~200 lines) the email just isn't received.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your MTA's log files? (They usually are in `/var/log/mail.log`.)

Comment: I have the same problem too. I found that the smaller emails were sent successfully but the larger emails weren't even showing up on any of the logs (mail.log, mail.warn, mail.err)